# Batch using dir to get folder destination (cmd) and copy+paste files in name's folder found

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, automation

Today I'm trying to do a script who'll automaticly move some files to my game folder (with xcopy). Here it's a simple batch, but my problem is, almost every month, the folder where I need to move my files is changing.
And I'm really lazy, so I would have a way to save the actual destionation folder (path), like using "dir" and saving it in a variable to be usable as destination with xcopy.

---

**LINK HERE --> [Architecture tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvwAX.png)**

**Important, there's only 1 folder EDIT:existing in destination folder** (may be easier ?).

Here is what I'm thinking, but it can't works, probably because there's too many informations.

> source -> *D:\MyMods*
>
> FULL NAME: D:\config\Games\WoWS\Mods\6) Skins\All_Skins(Modified)\
>
> destination -> *L:\games\mods\0.6.15.0*
>
> FULL NAME: L:\Games\World_of_Warships\res_mods

```
set version = dir "L:\Games\World_of_Warships\res_mods"
```

> middle result -> version = 0.6.15.0

```
xcopy "D:\source\" "L:\Games\World_of_Warships\res_mods\%version%\" /E /Y
```

> final result -> L:\Games\World_of_Warships\res_mods\0.6.15.0\FILES_COPIED

---

*PS: I've almost lost all my notions of batch, but by few research I usualy find what I'm trying to do, but here, I can't find it :|*

Thanks for all

**EDIT: Finaly founded "dir /AD /B" gives me exactly the correct name folder, but now I need to save it, or make it usuable in my xcopy**

**Tried: (not working)**

```
set version=NotSet
dir /AD /B "L:\Games\World_of_Warships\res_mods" > %version%
```

Finally, after many tries, here I got something, but it's just not working, for a reason that I can't see:

```
dir /AD /B "L:\Games\World_of_Warships\res_mods" > version.txt
set /P version=<version.txt
set "destination=L:\Games\World_of_Warships\res_mods\%version%\"
set "source=D:\config\Games\WoWS\Mods\6) Skins\All_Skins(Modified)\"
xcopy %source% %destination% /E /Y

echo %destination%
echo %source%
```

Here is the result:

> Number of parameters not valid  ---> *why ?*
>
> L:\Games\World_of_Warships\res_mods\0.6.15.0\  ---> *Correct*
>
> D:\config\Games\WoWS\Mods\6) Skins\All_Skins(Modified)\ ---> *Correct*

**EDIT2: I shortened folders's names to have something easier to "plan", then I only would need to use some " before and after the path, and then, it should work. But apparently, it's giving more troubles than anythings. Sorry for that.**

Thanks for that -1, but it would be better to say why you did it to not do the same mistake ;)

Comment: Are you trying to say that there will always be one-and-only-one folder under `L:\game\mods\`?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meaned, because everytime an other directory is created, the old one will be deleted (by an other way, so I don't need to delete it here with this script).

Comment: @Drexx, do you want d:\MyMods to contain a mirror of L:\Games\Mods or just copy any new bits into the destination?

Comment: @jwdonahue I got my mods files in my folder on my device D:, and I would like to copy and paste all it contains, to the folder of my game (L: device), but everytime, I had to do it manualy, and now I would like to have a script to do it, automaticly :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding, the reason you are getting this message is because of your incorrect and unnecessary trailing back slash to your `source` variable value.

This should not work:

```bat
Set "destination=L:\Games\World_of_Warships\res_mods\%version%\"
Set "source=D:\config\Games\WoWS\Mods\6) Skins\All_Skins(Modified)\"
XCopy "%source%" "%destination%" /E /Y
```

This should probably work *(optional)*:

```bat
Set "destination=L:\Games\World_of_Warships\res_mods\%version%\"
Set "source=D:\config\Games\WoWS\Mods\6) Skins\All_Skins(Modified)"
XCopy "%source%" "%destination%" /E /Y
```

This should work *(recommended)*:

```bat
Set "destination=L:\Games\World_of_Warships\res_mods\%version%"
Set "source=D:\config\Games\WoWS\Mods\6) Skins\All_Skins(Modified)"
XCopy "%source%" "%destination%" /E /Y
```

Putting it all together, your script would look like this:

```bat
Dir /B/AD-S-L "L:\Games\World_of_Warships\res_mods">"version.txt"
Set /P "version="<"version.txt"
Set "destination=L:\Games\World_of_Warships\res_mods\%version%"
Set "source=D:\config\Games\WoWS\Mods\6) Skins\All_Skins(Modified)"
XCopy "%source%" "%destination%" /E /Y

Echo=%destination%
Echo=%source%
```

**Edit**

To bypass the use of a text file, you could replace the first three lines above with this:

```bat
For /D %%A In ("L:\Games\World_of_Warships\res_mods\*") Do Set "destination=%%~fA"
```

*Remember that this will adequately retrieve the full path directory name when there is only one as you have stated*

If you wanted, *for safety*, to ensure you were using the most recently created directory name, then you could use this instead:

```bat
CD /D "L:\Games\World_of_Warships\res_mods" 2>Nul || Exit /B
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Dir /B/AD-S-L/OD/TC') Do Set "destination=%%~fA"
```

**Edit 2**

According to latest comment request, either:

```bat
Set "destination="
For /D %%A In ("L:\Games\World_of_Warships\res_mods\*"
) Do If Not Defined destination Set "destination=%%~fA"
```

Or use `Dir` with ordering to ensure you get the correct first one. *(`/ON` ordered by name, `/O-N` reverse ordered by name, or similarly with `/OD|/O-D` by date with `/TC|/TW` for created or written)*:

```bat
CD /D "L:\Games\World_of_Warships\res_mods" 2>Nul || Exit /B
Set "destination="
For /F "Delims=" %%A In ('Dir /B/AD-S-L/ON'
) Do If Not Defined destination Set "destination=%%~fA"
```

Comment: @jwdonahue, the problem is the back slash, try it with known directories as a test, you cannot have a trailing back slash for at least your source directory. It doesn't matter how you get the directory name, (the provided method works, as shown in the OP's question), adding a trailing back slash is what will prevent it copying _(unless you use a wildcard after it)_.

Comment: @jwdonahue, the OP said they used, `dir /AD /B "L:\Games\mods" > version.txt` then `set /P version=<version.txt` they followed that by showing `> L:\Games\mods\0.6.15.0\  ---> Correct`. Their post stated there's only ever one directory, the code appears to adequately identify it and their statement that it's correct is undeniable. What is evident is that simply removing the trailing back slash from `%source%` fixes the error and the files are copied as intended.

Comment: Their code is in a formatted block close to the foot of their current question. It contains five main lines, their first two work as they have shown, the next three were replaced in my answer above, do you really want me to show their already working `dir` and `set /P` lines when all they technically needed to do was remove a back slash or two?

Comment: No, I don't want anything from you, really.  I never should have made the first comment.  Comments removed.  I'll loop back and delete this one in a day or two.

Comment: @jwdonahue Well, I tried with \ or without, and there's any difference... But I've been using some \ because in the real name of directory, there is some spaces, and (), that's one reason, I did it

Comment: @Drexx, the spaces and parentheses in your directory name, e.g. `Program Files (x86)`, which are both not shown in any of your comments or question would be fully protected by enclosing them in double quotes as generally recommended and subsequently shown in my answer.

Comment: @Compo well, I've been always adding " before and an other " after, to have the string complete. But it changes anything

Comment: @Drexx, how about you post as an edit the real script, using the real paths, _(complete with spaces and parentheses)_. Make sure that the script is exactly as you're running it and explain what isn't working as intended. The methods used by yourself and others to get the directory name work and the method I and others used to copy works. If putting the two together fails then there's something you haven't mentioned, shown or done correctly. Noting the number of comments and answers given so far without a solution, then I'd suggest a complete question overhaul to be your best course of action.

Comment: I shortened the directory name, to have something easier to "plan", but I'm changing the name of the directory as the real one (despite it thought it wouldn't impact) Sorry for that

Comment: FINALY ! Using Compo method, I think it's just me who did something really stupid, I was trying to access a test folder in
`D:\config\Games\WoWS\Mods\6) Skins\test` 
But I just was adding " test " after "All_Skins(Modified)" to have
`D:\config\Games\WoWS\Mods\6) Skins\All_Skins(Modified)\test` . 
Was my bad. Sorry to forcing you to find something who doesn't exist ;)

Comment: Now, to "improve" the script, is there a way to directly save version path to a variable **without using txt file** ?

Comment: @Drexx, I've added an Edit section to my answer which may help you out.

Comment: @compo Thank you for this. Could you say me exactly how that "for" is working ? I'm curious, because I never know (or I forgot, I don't know) what does it do ? Like the /D is to check directory (check cmd /?), %%A, variable who'll be used (creating it). "In" that's the folder then it's reading, "Do set", command that must be used. "destination=%%~fA" what is it ? I guess that's where it registers name's folder, but how does it do that ?**

Comment: @Compo Hello, I was trying to improve a bit the script you helped me to do, but it's not really doing what I want. I've got this line
 {For /D %%A In ("L:\Games\World_of_Warships\res_mods\*") Do Set "destination=%%~fA"} and I would like to save on the variable "destination" only the first result, how could I do that ? And just a personnal question, how could I see each result saved to the variable in for command ?

Comment: @Drexx, please see **Edit 2**, for my suggestion. And for seeing it, just change it to read,  `(Echo %%A&Set "destination=%%~fA")`.

Comment: @Compo Perfect and thanks for all, in edit 2, first choice works perfectly, but second one got some weird bug. It gives me the name of folder "0.7.2.1" but put path of source path. Result: "D:\config\Games\WoWS\Mods\0.7.2.1" Folder path "L:\Games\World_of_Warships\res_mods\0.7.2.1"

Comment: I'm glad it's working for you! _I have made a modification to the second option to hopefully correct the bug you reported._

Comment: @Compo Good to know. And I've also test with the first choice, you can delete first line with [Set "destination="] because you already set it in the "for". I did it, and it works perfectly, and I removed 1 line. PS: use the @ user to notice me when you answer, or I risk to not see your message :)

Comment: @Drexx, that line, `Set "destination="` is there for a good reason. There's no way of knowing if a variable already exists, if one does then the `If Not Defined destination` would fail. It could technically be changed to, `If Defined destination Set "destination="`, but it has a necessary purpose. _Removing it only works for you because you don't have an existing environment variable named `destination`_. My understanding  is that the question starter is notified of every comment or answer, without being specifically named.

Answer (score 0):

```
for /d %%d in ("destination\*") do xcopy /y "source\*" "%%d\"
```

where `source` is your source directory (D:\MyMods) and `destination` is your destination directory's parent (L:\game\mods) which contains exactly one subdirectory (0.1.4.7)

-- modified to correct destination specification --

Here's my test setup, just so there's no misunderstanding:

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir\mods"
for /d %%d in ("%destdir%\*") do xcopy /y /e "%sourcedir%\*" "%%d\"

DIR /s "%destdir%"
DIR /s "%sourcedir%"

GOTO :EOF
```

Note that I omitted the `/e` from the `xcopy` - I customarily use `/s`, but looks like I'll need to change my policy...

I had just one subdirectory under `U:\destdir\mods`, and the entire subtree under `U:\sourcedir` was copied under that subdirectory.

---

try again, this time using parentheses and spaces in both filename and directorynames.

*slightly* modified code. source and destination directorynames changed to include parentheses and spaces. `dir/s` used to report directory-tree structure and `find` used to filter out `.` and `..` which just clutter output.

```dos
@ECHO Off
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir\t (w) o"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir\mo (d) s"
ECHO --- before structure ---
DIR /s "%sourcedir%"|FIND /v " ."
DIR /s "%destdir%"|FIND /v " ."
ECHO -------------------------

for /d %%d in ("%destdir%\*") do xcopy /y /e "%sourcedir%\*" "%%d\"

ECHO --- after structure ---

DIR /s "%destdir%"|FIND /v " ."

GOTO :EOF
```

Result

```
--- before structure ---
 Volume in drive U has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 3490-2000

 Directory of U:\sourcedir\t (w) o

28/12/2017  22:01                 0 dum myfile2.txt
28/12/2017  22:01    <DIR>          subd (i) r1
28/12/2017  22:01    <DIR>          subd (i) r2
28/12/2017  22:01                 0 fil (e)_1.txt
28/12/2017  22:01                 0 fil (e)_2.txt
               3 File(s)              0 bytes

 Directory of U:\sourcedir\t (w) o\subd (i) r1

28/12/2017  22:01                 0 fil (e)_3.ext
28/12/2017  22:01                 0 fil (e)_4.ext
28/12/2017  22:01                 0 fil (e)_5.ext
               3 File(s)              0 bytes

 Directory of U:\sourcedir\t (w) o\subd (i) r2

28/12/2017  22:01                 0 fil (e)_3.ext
28/12/2017  22:01                 0 fil (e)_4.ext
28/12/2017  22:01                 0 fil (e)_5.ext
               3 File(s)              0 bytes

     Total Files Listed:
               9 File(s)              0 bytes
               8 Dir(s)   2,592,260,096 bytes free
 Volume in drive U has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 3490-2000

 Directory of U:\destdir\mo (d) s

28/12/2017  22:01    <DIR>          0.6.( 15 ).0
               0 File(s)              0 bytes

 Directory of U:\destdir\mo (d) s\0.6.( 15 ).0

               0 File(s)              0 bytes

     Total Files Listed:
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               5 Dir(s)   2,592,260,096 bytes free
-------------------------
U:\sourcedir\t (w) o\dum myfile2.txt
U:\sourcedir\t (w) o\fil (e)_1.txt
U:\sourcedir\t (w) o\fil (e)_2.txt
U:\sourcedir\t (w) o\subd (i) r1\fil (e)_3.ext
U:\sourcedir\t (w) o\subd (i) r1\fil (e)_4.ext
U:\sourcedir\t (w) o\subd (i) r1\fil (e)_5.ext
U:\sourcedir\t (w) o\subd (i) r2\fil (e)_3.ext
U:\sourcedir\t (w) o\subd (i) r2\fil (e)_4.ext
U:\sourcedir\t (w) o\subd (i) r2\fil (e)_5.ext
9 File(s) copied
--- after structure ---
 Volume in drive U has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 3490-2000

 Directory of U:\destdir\mo (d) s

28/12/2017  22:01    <DIR>          0.6.( 15 ).0
               0 File(s)              0 bytes

 Directory of U:\destdir\mo (d) s\0.6.( 15 ).0

28/12/2017  22:01                 0 dum myfile2.txt
28/12/2017  22:01                 0 fil (e)_1.txt
28/12/2017  22:01                 0 fil (e)_2.txt
28/12/2017  22:01    <DIR>          subd (i) r1
28/12/2017  22:01    <DIR>          subd (i) r2
               3 File(s)              0 bytes

 Directory of U:\destdir\mo (d) s\0.6.( 15 ).0\subd (i) r1

28/12/2017  22:01                 0 fil (e)_3.ext
28/12/2017  22:01                 0 fil (e)_4.ext
28/12/2017  22:01                 0 fil (e)_5.ext
               3 File(s)              0 bytes

 Directory of U:\destdir\mo (d) s\0.6.( 15 ).0\subd (i) r2

28/12/2017  22:01                 0 fil (e)_3.ext
28/12/2017  22:01                 0 fil (e)_4.ext
28/12/2017  22:01                 0 fil (e)_5.ext
               3 File(s)              0 bytes

     Total Files Listed:
               9 File(s)              0 bytes
              11 Dir(s)   2,592,251,904 bytes free
```

So - all I can say is that it works for me, spaces, parentheses and all...

Comment: When I don't use * after path, it's saying "access path not valid", and when I'm using it, it says File not found - *

Comment: To which \* do you refer?

Comment: for /d %%d in ("destination\ * <- HERE") do xcopy /y "source\ * <- HERE" "destination\%%d\"

Comment: Still got the same message: " file not found - * " And " 0 file copied "

Comment: Is it possible I got this message, because there is "spaces" and () ?

Comment: Now, at the end, it's just doing a list of all files in source directory, and in the destination directory, but if I take out `DIR /s "%destdir%" ` and `DIR /s "%sourcedir%"` I got `file not found - *` and `0 file copied`

Comment: FINALY ! Using Compo method, I think it's just me who did something really stupid, I was trying to access a test folder in
`D:\config\Games\WoWS\Mods\6) Skins\test` 
But I just was adding " test " after "All_Skins(Modified)" to have
`D:\config\Games\WoWS\Mods\6) Skins\All_Skins(Modified)\test` . 
Was my bad. Sorry to forcing you to find something who doesn't exist ;)